# Does Zer0's "Execute" damage depend on deception time?

Tags: borderlands-2

Since normal melee damage is affected by the time left for your deception mode, I wonder whether the same is true for Zer0's "Execute" skill.

**EDIT:** Thanks Keith for pointing that out ... so how is the actual damage calculated?

> a) Melee * (1 + Deception Bonus + Execute bonus)
>   b) Melee * Execute bonus
>   c) Execute Damage

Comment: Do you mean: does Execute damage stack with the deception bonus (i.e. `6 x melee + bonus`), override it (i.e. `6 x melee` or `melee + bonus`) or enhance it (i.e. `6 x (melee + bonus)`)?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wiki,

> Execute doubles the usual damage bonus granted by Decepti0n

So that'd be `melee` * (2 * `Decepti0n`).

In my own experience I've found that to be roughly accurate, I've found it difficult to perfectly time the same amount of bonus given by `Decepti0n`.

Answer (score 1):

[User Zikel, in the /r/Borderlands subreddit tested Deception with Execute](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/15op84/many_skill_descriptions_are_misleading_dont_tell/) and came up with the ff. results:

> Deception, [gives a bonus of] ...**a minimum of 230%** up to
> +650% Melee Damage...
>
> #### Execute
>
> How much exactly is this "massive damage"? This skill changes the
> melee damage bonus of deception from: a minimum of 230% up to 650% Melee damage to **a minimum of 460% up to 1400% increased Melee damage**.

---

<sup>Source: [Reddit /r/Borderlands post by user Zikel, "*Many skill descriptions are misleading, don't tell the full story or straight up lie to you. I took it upon my self to test EVERYTHING and clear up the confusion. Here are the results.*"](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/15op84/many_skill_descriptions_are_misleading_dont_tell/)</sup>